# How to limit the number of wireless networks listed in the wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

When cliking on the "network" icon in the top bar / wingpanel, 3 sections are displayed:

- Wired
- Wireless
- VPN

My problem is that I see so many wireless networks that I can't actually see the VPN section, or not fully, as shown in the screenshot below (network names redacted for privacy).
[image: Screenshot of the issue: VPN section not fully visible]

How can I limit (or remove completely) the "wireless networks" section? I am using Loki.

Comment: How should that work to remove completely the wireless networks section? Which network should be chosen? And again, with a limit: which one should be hidden?

Comment: It's not because it wouldn't be shown in the wingpanel that it wouldn't exist. The network parameters (including wireless networks) would still be accessible through the configuration panel.

Comment: @bigbang Simple: you could just show the wireless network you're connected to. If you need to change network, you click to disconnect then all networks are shown. Of course, if you're not connected to any network, then all networks are shown. This seems reasonable as once you're connected, you usually don't care about other wifi networks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality. But there is a bug over there at [Github](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network/issues/23) which is similar. Please elaborate there your wishes as in the last comments here. Some of your ideas seems worth to discuss there.

Comment: Perfect, i just did that - hopefully this will get resolved and I'll update in this thread. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark my answer as solving the question then. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it was helpful but it's hardly solving the question. There's no out of the box way of doing it, but I'm sure it could be done by tinkering with internal config files for example.

Comment: I don‘t want to nitpick, but your question is answered. Your problem is not solved, though.